# Failed to install Npgsql (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-code, npgsql

I'm having trouble with installing Npgsql in Visual Studio Code (.Net Core 3.1.1).

I create a clean project and try install package.
`dotnet new console`
`dotnet add package Npgsql --version 4.1.2`

The package fails to install and I receive a message:

> The Npgsql package is not compatible with all architectures in the
>   project.. I found a similar problem here, but it was solved by
>   updating NuGet. Which probably won't be my case. What am I doing wrong
>   and how to install the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Installing a package using the `dotnet add package package-name` command does not work for me. But if I install the NuGet Gallery extension (in the VS code) and add a package using this tool, then the library will install properly.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to provide more details about the environment, the platform you are using. I tried creating the same on windows 10 with dot net 3.1.100 and it added the package successfully using visual studio code and VS 2019.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

   <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="npgsql" Version="4.1.2" />
   </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Sorry, here's information about the environment:
.NET Core SDK: Version:   3.1.101
Runtime enviromment:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.18363
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win10-x64
.NET Core SDKs installed:
3.1.101
And how did you install the package? Using the _dotnet add package Npgsql_?

Comment: Looks similar environment as mine. In Visual Code, package was added using the command you specified from the terminal. And in Visual Studio through Nuget Package manager.

Comment: It looks like this problem [link](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5127).